# What is the best way to make a parent program that runs and manage multiple child programs in Python?

Tags: python, multiprocess

I have a Python program that runs facial recognition service. The program comes with a Tornado server that serves a UI so I can see the recognition result. I have a few IP cameras and I want each of these cameras to have separate recognition service.

What I did right now is:

```
import subprocess
import user_config

port = 9000
for cam in user_config.CAMERA_ID:
    command = "python recognition.py -camid "+cam+" -port "+str(port)
    p = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    port = port+1
```

Is this a good way to do this? If let say one of the processes died, how do I check and bring it back up?

Comment: Not too surprisingly, using the [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing) module would be good approach.

Comment: You can use [`Popen.poll()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.poll) to check if a subprocess is still running and, if not, respawn it. But given that you're running a Python process, why not just import the file and run it directly via [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html), or even [`threading`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) if its main function is I/O bound.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

- `multiprocessing`

run a function in an other process, you can give args through `args` and `kwargs`.
you can use shared `Variable` and `Array` with this strategy

- `subprocess`

run an other script with the command line, you can pass args in the string and get them back through `sys.argv`